# How to add select all checkbox to list of checkboxes in react

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

This is my initial state

```
class RoomAmmenitiesForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data: {
      free_toiletries: false,
      blackout_drapes: false,
      safe_deposit_box: false,
      lcd_tv: false,
      free_wifi: false,
      pay_tv: false,
    }}
```

This is my checkbox handler function

```
toggleCheckbox = (e) => {
    const AmmenityBoxName = e.target.name;
    this.setState((state) => ({
      data: {
        ...state.data,
        [AmmenityBoxName]: !state.data[AmmenityBoxName],
      },
    }));
  };
```

This is the render code for select all checkbox

```
<div className="form-check">
            <label className="container">
              <input
                name= ?? <----------What name should i put here
                type="checkbox"
                checked={this.state.data}
                onChange={this.toggleAllCheckboxes}
                className="form-check-input"
              />
              <span className="checkmark"></span>
              Select All
            </label>
          </div>
```

How do i add a function to handle checking and unchecking all checkboxes? Kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
toggleAllCheckboxes = (check) => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      data: Object.keys(state.data).reduce((acc, key) => {
          acc[key] = check;
          return acc;
      }, {})
    }));
}
```

You iterate through `state.data` keys and create a new object which has all properties equal to either true or false.

And your checkbox should look like this:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   checked={Object.keys(this.state.data).every(k => this.state.data[k])}
   onChange={e => this.toggleAllCheckboxes(e.target.checked)}
/>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-fire-zlkiq)

Comment: Thanks. This is working on checking. Does not uncheck

Comment: checking or unchecking depends on what you pass to the function.

Comment: My implementation is that i want to be able to check and uncheck all the checkboxes. Your implementation enable checking all boxes but not unchecking even when clicking on single checkbox

Comment: Can you add more details to your question about what you wanna do?

Comment: i have added render code for select all checkbox. I believe the problem is on the name property of the input type. what should i use?

Comment: I've updated my answer, you don't need a name on that checkbox